# JS function returns null - help

Tags: javascript, fileapi

I am trying to modify the example http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files to make function handleFileSelect(evt)  return reader.result; I mean to make function return base64 for image or so.
I tried to write it with function but it returns null only :( 
So my question is how to make the function return base64?

As for now I tried to write this snippet...

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                            '" title="', theFile.name, '"/>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
    return reader.result;
  }
```

All useful comments are appreciated :)

Comment: Please post the code that is giving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the FileReader object in detail, but it looks like it reads data from a URL asynchronously.  That means that when your function returns reader.result, the FileReader object isn't done reading the file yet.  That doesn't finish until the onload callback is called (or some other error condition occurs).

So, your function returns while the reading is still happening asynchronously.  Thus the result has not yet been determined.  The result would be available on side the onload callback or (I'm guessing), inside other callbacks that would signify error conditions (onabort, onerror, etc..).

Comment: I think that too. But I think how to make it return the result?

Comment: You can't return the result from that function.  If you want to know the result, then you have to hook the various event handlers (you already are hooking onload) and then from those event handlers, you can communicate the result to whatever you need to communicate it to.  This is asynchronous programming - you have to do it differently.

Comment: @jfriend00 yep ... @user592704 This is the new paradigm of javascript programming. It may look like C, but it ain't C.

Comment: So when it works as e.target.result ? but what if just to call the element by its id? I mean not when a 'file' button clicked but anytime it contains an url?

Comment: @user592704: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I mean... How to catch the filled array to have it not just with some dynamic image but with a JS object (var) and keep it accessable while the web page is running?

Comment: In the onload function (which is called asynchronously when it completes), you would need to store the result either in some existing persistent object or in a global variable or call some function that would store it where you want it.  The simplest incarnation of that would be to just declare a global JS variable and put it in that global variable.

Comment: I tried to init var with the reader.result but it is always null :( Help